# 18.04 Need Help installing more programs on live/persistent USB

Tags: software-installation, live-usb, storage

No answer has been given [here, which is similar.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1197061/need-help-updating-initramfs?newreg=fbbfff55c2034253bb492e3ba666ce4b#comment2007464_1197061)
I am trying to install [Grace](http://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Grace/) on my persistant live USB (I have already installed and used GROMACS after restarts, so I know the drive is working).

I get the following when I try to install a pre-req package (x11):

> update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
>   cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of overlay
>   cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
>   cp: error writing '/cdrom/casper/initrd.gz.new': No space left on device
>   dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
>    installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
>   Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.9) ...
>   update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
>   cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of overlay
>   cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
>   cp: error writing '/cdrom/casper/initrd.gz.new': No space left on device
>   dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
>    installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    linux-firmware
>    initramfs-tools
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

If it matters, I'm running 18.04LTS and am a Linux n00b.

As the other thread OP stated, I have a few Gigs of storage free.  Unlike in that thread, I have no idea what package is giving me trouble.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pretty much everything you need to know is right there in your output. Remember that a Live system is just a snapshot of a working system - you cannot install packages that require re-creating initramfs...which is what your output shows you are trying to do. Instead, you can actually install a real Ubuntu system (not a Live snapshot) onto your USB drive.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator

Comment: A Full install to USB will do everything an internal install will do, including proprietary drivers, updates, upgrades, kernel upgrades, etc, etc.